# How to Convert Model to ViewModel in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Here is my code:

```
public List<DiscountVM> GetAllDiscounts(long CompanyID)
    {

        return _context.Discounts.Where(x => x.IsActive == true && x.CompanyID == CompanyID).Select(s => new DiscountVM()
        {
            DiscountID = s.DiscountID,
            LocationID = s.LocationID,
            CompanyID = s.CompanyID,
            DiscountName = s.DiscountName,
            DiscountValue = s.DiscountValue,
            DiscountType = s.DiscountType,
            ServiceSale = s.ServiceSale,
            ProductSale = s.ProductSale,
            VoucherSale = s.VoucherSale,
            IsActive = s.IsActive,
            AddDate = s.AddDate,
            AddedByID = s.AddedByID,
            UpdateDate = s.UpdateDate,
            UpdatedByID = s.UpdatedByID,
        }).ToList();
    }
```

I want to convert Model to View model because if i am not converting then i have to fill all the values.

The code is working fine if I fill all the values. I trying to find a way in which I can easily convert the model to view model then there would be no need to fill all the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well this can be done some different way but easiest way for you that change you view model a little bit by adding you db model as property of your view model like this

```
 public class DiscountVM
     {
        public Discounts DiscountsList{ get; set; }
        // Other property
     }
```

and return like this

```
public List<DiscountVM> GetAllDiscounts(long CompanyID)
{
    return _context.Discounts.Where(x => x.IsActive == true && x.CompanyID ==CompanyID).Select(s => new DiscountVM()
    {
        DiscountsList=s
    }).ToList();

}
```

Comment: Thanks Alot .You save my day.This is exactly what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) to help you with that?

Comment: i have looked AutoMapper but dont think so it solve my probelm .